# Iteration parameter in latent dirichlet allocation model

Tags: topic-models

I want to find 24 topics in 800,000 documents by using LDA model, but how many iterations should I give? It is extremely slow when the parameter is large, like 3000.

Are there any strategies to ensure the stability? Seems giving the iteration a large value is the only way I can think of.

Comment: Questions pertaining to processing speed are not a great fit for CV. Perhaps what you want to know is something along the lines of how many are required to ensure the stability of result?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for not asking the right answer. Are there any strategies to ensure the stability? Seems giving the iteration a large value is the only way I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

You can try getting the logPerplexity per iteration and check on a graph when it converges.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @ArjunVariar. This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our standards. But I think there is a real & valuable answer here. Can you expand
on it? We can also turn it into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to guess the appropriate number of iterations, you can evaluate the perplexity of the model at every $k$ iterations, and check whether the change is within a chosen tolerance.

For example, the `scikit-learn` [implementation of LDA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.html) lets you set this via the `evaluate_every` and `perp_tol` parameters. This [excerpt form the source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/decomposition/online_lda.py#L518) demonstrates how it's done:

```
if evaluate_every > 0 and (i + 1) % evaluate_every == 0:
    doc_topics_distr, _ = self._e_step(X, cal_sstats=False,
                                        random_init=False,
                                        parallel=parallel)
    bound = self.perplexity(X, doc_topics_distr,
                            sub_sampling=False)
    if self.verbose:
        print('iteration: %d, perplexity: %.4f'
                % (i + 1, bound))

    if last_bound and abs(last_bound - bound) < self.perp_tol:
        break
    last_bound = bound
self.n_iter_ += 1
```